# Custom back ground for owner drawn menu

Tags: c++, winapi

Im using mfc to draw a custom menu except it has a nasty looking border around it. How do i get rid of the border or draw over it?

For example:

[image]

(the white border around the edge)

Edit:

i know its only three hours left but none of the things below work. I have tried them using the following code:

```
    HWND hwnd = m_pParent->getBrowserHWND();
    uint32 style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style&~WS_BORDER);
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    HookHwnd hook(hwnd);
    int res = TrackPopupMenu((HMENU)menu.GetHMenu(), TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_RIGHTBUTTON|TPM_RETURNCMD|TPM_RECURSE, xPos, yPos, 0, hwnd, NULL);

    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

Comment: Me too, although I understand the need to remove the border.  Any chance you can post your project somewhere, so we can tinker with the code???

Answer (score 1):

Actually further to freefallr's advice it may well just be a simple WS_BORDER.

Try removing it using:

```
ModifyStyle( WS_BORDER, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED );
```

Answer (score 0):

I only use WTL for UI coding, it's been years since I've looked at MFC, but it's also very close to the Windows API.  You might check the creation flags for the menu.

Call [GetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584%28VS.85%29.aspx) and specifically, check GWL_EXSTYLE for WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE; this *may* be the cause of your problem.  You can always OR it out and call [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx) and redraw the menu to test.

Hope this is of some help!

Update:
I wonder if the frame isn't being updated.  Try:

ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

Comment: See update above - try ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

Comment: i awarded you the bounty as you need the xp but still cant get it working. If i have time i might post an example project

Comment: Thanks lodle, please post a project on source forge or something and put the link up here and I'll have a look!!